# Changing PHP Session Variable with POST

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have been trying to create some custom filters for my mysql and PHP table, If you see my previous post I was a little lost with where to go.

Think I've found a solution, but It's not quite working. At this point security does not matter at this is just a personal project, but Id love to get it working.

So I store a $result_else variable with the following:

```
$_SESSION['result_else'] = $result_else;

$result_else = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE     GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 25");
```

I use a An html select, and form to link to my filter.php

I wish to change the sql query to this for testing purposes:

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
require '../games/game.php';
if(isset($_POST['add_region']))
{

$_SESSION['result_else'] = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE AND guard = 'Asia' GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 25");


//echo "Entered data successfully\n";
//echo '<a href="index.php">Go home</a>';
}

?>
```

This is currently giving me no errors, and just displaying the original game.php page ?
Kind of stumped on where to go from here as I have tried quite a few things and have never worked with SESSION variables.

Also this is my html form

```
<form method="POST" action="../inc/filter.php">
<select class="form-control" name="add_region" onchange="this.form.submit();">
  <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
  <option value="Eur">Eur</option>
</select>
    </form>
```

PS: Im quite new to programming, and PHP in particular

Comment: Have you started the session?

Comment: There is info on sessions here. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: @fred -ii- Ive started the session in the header.php like so <?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

Comment: @Funk Doc That is exactly what I was following

Comment: I wonder what do you expect to be the difference. In both cases the result will be mysqli resource

Comment: @Royal Bg Was expecting the table to echo out with the new sql statement providing only rows where the region(guard) is Asia

Comment: @Kepoly this might be a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php

Comment: @Kepoly dont know how do you use the session, but I think you do expect it to be an array of something, but mysqli_query returns only statement, no raw data structure

Comment: @RoyalBg I am trying to switch my original mysqli query that is inside of my $return_else variable to the new one that contains an added WHERE statement

Answer (score 0):

Should it be something like?

You store the 'basic' query if the session variable 'result_else' is empty.

if you provide a new query then you replace the session variable with that.

Once you change the query in the session variable it will keep it until you change it again.

Completely untested.

```
if (empty($_SESSION['result_else']) { // set the basic query
    $_SESSION['result_else'] = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE     GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 25";      
}

if(isset($_POST['add_region'])) { // set the new query
    $_SESSION['result_else'] = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE AND guard = 'Asia' GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
}

// Alway run the 'current' query to get the results.
$result_else = mysqli_query($con, $_SESSION['result_else');
```

Comment: Could also be done with a ternary operation. Cleaning up a lot of if statements for multiple requirements. `SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE ". (isset($_POST['add_region']) ? "AND guard = 'Asia'" : "") ." GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 25`

Comment: @TomKriek, Was tryin' to make it clear how the logic worked. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for the help, So i have your solution working without errors, and this is what the printf is returning for sessions `Array
(
    [result_else] => SELECT * FROM game WHERE listDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE AND guard = 'Asia' GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 25
)` So it is returning the correct value / string but the table does not change when returning to it with a `echo "<script>window.location = '../games/game.php'</script>";`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this working almost to what id like, 
This is obviously not a good practice but it will work for now until can find a better solution!

Created a page called game-(filter Name).php and just echoed out the mysqli query with the guard = 'Asia' included and added the same formatting from game.php so the page looks the same. Is there a better way to create tables with jquery(AJAX) and still use mysql/php ?

Everything looks good and works but this just doesn't seem right!